# How do I allocate memory from JS at specific locations of the wasm memory buffer?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

I want to set specific values at the first N bytes of a wasm memory buffer and pass it to the wasm module. So I do something like this in my JS code:

```
const array = new Int32Array(memory.buffer, 0, 5)
array.set([3, 15, 18, 4, 2])
```

... and the guest c++ function can take a pointer to the first location and an int for the length of the array, and do something with the values.

My question is: If I want to make sure that these bytes are not overwritten by any c++ code that might run subsequently and allocate memory, is there a best practice to do so? i.e. I want to make sure that the first N bytes are only set on the JS side.

Comment: Build your own allocator in C++ that'll only allocate from the nth byte onwards.

Comment: Probably best to call `Module._malloc` to allocate some space (or `Module.stackAlloc` if you know the lifetime of memory won't out live the native call you are making), rather then using the start of the buffer.   Emscripten reserves the first 1024 bytes an invalid memory locations so tools like asan and other memory checking tools assume reads and write to the these locations are invalid.